# Selenium driver does not reflect the page changes after click()

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I want to get stock list on etoro.

But when I trying to click on selenium => After making click(), I want to get the elements already updated but the elements all the same as before click()

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/stocks/exchange/nasdaq?ExchangeID=4")

stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)

next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.nav-button-right")
next.click()

print("------------------------------------")

stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)
```

Output:

```
TSLA
AMZN
AAPL
MSFT
META
NVDA
GOOG
PYPL
AMD
NFLX
INTC
COIN
GOOGL
SEDG
ADBE
ABNB
CRWD
MELI
ASML
BIDU
FSLR
ENPH
ATVI
NTDOY
PLUG
BNGO
CRSR
WBD
CSCO
MU
VRTX
TLRY
ETSY
HAS
QCOM
ACB
BYND
PTON
ZM
HST
RIVN
BKNG
ROKU
SOFI
PEP
TROW
SBUX
RUN
STNE
CSIQ
------------------------------------
TSLA
AMZN
AAPL
MSFT
META
NVDA
GOOG
PYPL
AMD
NFLX
INTC
COIN
GOOGL
SEDG
ADBE
ABNB
CRWD
MELI
ASML
BIDU
FSLR
ENPH
ATVI
NTDOY
PLUG
BNGO
CRSR
WBD
CSCO
MU
VRTX
TLRY
ETSY
HAS
QCOM
ACB
BYND
PTON
ZM
HST
RIVN
BKNG
ROKU
SOFI
PEP
TROW
SBUX
RUN
STNE
CSIQ
```

Selenium driver keeps old data after click
What am I missing? How to get the elements of the last loaded page

Thank you!

---

@Yaroslavm
This is my code edited as your proposal, but the result is still the same. I can not get the stock list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/stocks/exchange/nasdaq?ExchangeID=4")

def wait_for_values_not_equal(value_func, value, timeout=10, interval=0.5):
    start_time = time.time()

    while value_func() == value:
        print(value_func())
        print(value)
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not change within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)

    return value_func() != value

def nav_stamp():
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > app-root > et-layout-main > div > div.container-level2.layout-sidenav-collapsed.layout-sidenav-closed > div.container-level3 > div.page-content > div > ui-layout > ng-view > et-discovery-markets-results > div > et-discovery-markets-results-header > div > div.inner-menu > div > div.result-amount-wrap > span.pager-list.ng-star-inserted")

stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)

# next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.nav-button-right")
# next.click()

nav_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > app-root > et-layout-main > div > div.container-level2.layout-sidenav-collapsed.layout-sidenav-closed > div.container-level3 > div.page-content > div > ui-layout > ng-view > et-discovery-markets-results > div > et-discovery-markets-results-header > div > div.inner-menu > div > div.result-amount-wrap > span.pager-list.ng-star-inserted").text
print(nav_text)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.nav-button-right"))).click()
nav_text = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > app-root > et-layout-main > div > div.container-level2.layout-sidenav-collapsed.layout-sidenav-closed > div.container-level3 > div.page-content > div > ui-layout > ng-view > et-discovery-markets-results > div > et-discovery-markets-results-header > div > div.inner-menu > div > div.result-amount-wrap > span.pager-list.ng-star-inserted").text
print(nav_text)
wait_for_values_not_equal(nav_stamp, nav_text)

print("------------------------------------")

stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)
```

I see problem is: after everything is loaded => stock list is the same
Could you check this ticket:

> [Chrome driver does not update data from server(content in the browser not changed) after clicking as when I click manual on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844423/chrome-driver-does-not-update-data-from-servercontent-in-the-browser-not-change)

Answer (score 1):

Your resource has anti-scrapping Cloudflare protection, to avoid it you need to use `undetected chromedriver`.

[Installation](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

Also, as far as your resource loads stocks async, you need wait for several conditions to be completed to know, that page is changed and new stocks are rendered.

As one of approaches, you can wait for navigation text to be changed, previous first stock element not to exist and click on nav button until it wouldn't contain class `disable`

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = uc.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/stocks/exchange/nasdaq?ExchangeID=4")

def wait_for_values_not_equal(value_func, value, timeout=10, interval=0.5):
    start_time = time.time()

    while value_func() == value:
        print(value_func())
        print(value)
        if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
            raise TimeoutError("Timeout: Value did not change within the specified time.")
        time.sleep(interval)

    return value_func() != value

def nav_stamp():
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[automation-id=discover-market-pager-wrapp]').text

def get_stocks():
    return driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[automation-id=trade-item-name]")

def get_next_button():
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[automation-id=discover-market-next-button]")

stockList = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[automation-id=discover-market-pager-wrapp]')))
while 'disabled' not in get_next_button().get_attribute('class'):
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(get_next_button()))
    stocks = get_stocks()
    first_stock_text = stocks[0].text
    for stock in stocks:
        if(stock.text):
            print(stock.text)
            stockList.append(stock.text)

    nav_text_old = nav_stamp()
    get_next_button().click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[automation-id=discover-market-pager-wrapp]')))
    print('_________')
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[automation-id=trade-item-name]")))
    wait_for_values_not_equal(nav_stamp, nav_text_old)
    try:
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(stocks[0]))
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you check this question in detail:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76844423/chrome-driver-does-not-update-data-from-servercontent-in-the-browser-not-change

Comment: I tried you proposal but even after: text in nav bar is changed => stock list in browser still is the same before as clicking

Comment: This is my code edited:

Comment: @PhamNgocDinh try updated code snippet