# Chrome driver does not update data from server(content in the browser not changed) after clicking as when I click manual on Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

When I open manual url on Chrome, the first page is:
[image]

and click manually to move the next page of stock list, I see after loading => stock list are updated

[image]

but when I run my code and auto open Chrome Driver => make a click to move the next page of stock list on Chrome Driver, the stock list are **not updated**, there are the same data as before clicking.

[image]

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/discover/markets/stocks/exchange/nasdaq?ExchangeID=4")

stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)

next = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.nav-button-right")
next.click()

print("------------------------------------")
name = input("BY PASS ")

if name == "a":
  print("BY PASS")
  
stockList = []
et_instrument_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "et-instrument-row.ng-star-inserted")
for et_instrument_row in et_instrument_rows:
    stock = et_instrument_row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.symbol").text
    print(stock)
    stockList.append(stock)


driver.quit()
```

Could you help me how to make stock list are updated when clicking on chrome driver by running my code

Thank you!